Books Covering Isometries in the Hyperboloid Model of the Hyperbolic Plane in Detail
I am looking for any books that cover the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane in more than passing mention. I am wanting a thorough reference material for performing transforms under this model.
Essentially what I am wanting is this section of the Wikipedia page for the model, but with greater detail. I have looked but have not found the source of the article's information, and would like more information regarding it anyway. Ideally a source would include derivations of these isometries.
Physical books preferred, but PDFs acceptable. It is not necessary a book be solely focused on this model, just so long as any sections regarding it are detailed as stated.

the 1993 article by Reynolds that they reference seems pretty good.

@WillJagy Oh, so that seems to be where that section came from. I would still like to leave this question open as I would like to have a physical book if one exists on this topic.

Did you try Ratcliffe's book?
